# Trouble Installing Pygame on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, pygame

Here is my error message:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygame
>>>
```

So 2.7 can't find pygame.  This is on a new installation of python, and I'm able to get to my other modules (pyo,wx,numpy).  I have reinstalled pygame and looked among the respective library folders and I can't find the pygame module anywhere.  A reinstallation does not fix this.  Any Advice?

EDIT: In response to questions as to how I installed pygame, I installed from the .dmg located here http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml 'pygame-1.9.1release-python.org-32bit-py2.7-macosx10.3.dmg '

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The instructions differ if you have a 32-bit proccessor or a 64-bit one. Users of 32-bit processors should just download and install the binary labeled pygame-1.9.1release-python.org-32bit-py2.7-macosx10.3.dmg on the [pygame download page](http://pygame.org/download.shtml). Users of 64-bit processors should follow the instructions below.

1. There is no 64-bit version of pygame for Mac OS X. The 32-bit version of pygame is only compatible with a 32-bit version of python.
   However, there is a warning/caution to be aware of: on Snow Leopard the Apple-provided version of Tcl/Tk (a GUI library which powers IDLE) can be out-of-date and cause problems. Snow Leopard users should first download and install an updated version from [here](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads), labeled ActiveTcl 8.4.19.5 under Mac OS X (Universal).
   This should be installed first.
   Lion users should ignore this step.
2. Delete, if already installed, the Python 2.7 folder (most likely in /Applications). This is most likely the 64-bit version of Python that should not be used.
3. Download and install the 32-bit version of Python 2.7.2 provided [here](http://python.org/download/) under Python 2.7.2 Mac OS X 32-bit i386/PPC Installer.
   Regardless of what download page says, this version is compatible on Mac OS X Lion. If you have the correct version, the install size (as displayed in Installer) should be around 90 MB.
4. Download and install the 32-bit version of pygame, located [here](http://pygame.org/download.shtml).
5. You can test to see if this has worked by opening IDLE, and typing:
   import pygame

If there is no output, it worked. If instead you get a "no matching architecture in universal wrapper" error, then most likely step 2 was skipped.

Comment: This has quite some implications. All your 64-bit installed libraries won't work anymore! There are ways to install a 32-bit python installation next to a 64-bit one, which is a little bit less invasive...

Answer (score 4):

I installed this http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip

and this: http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

All started working.

Comment: not ALL. E.g create_tag_image(tags, 'cloud_large.png', size=(900, 600), fontname='Lobster')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytagcloud/__init__.py", line 350, in create_tag_image
    pygame.image.save(image_surface, output)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/imageext.so, 2): Symbol not found: _IMG_Load
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/imageext.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/imageext.so

Comment: it worked for me. I tried to install the package named for macosx10.6 and didint worked. This package you mentioned for macos10.7 worked. thanks

Comment: If I had a million dollars, I would give you one! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to copy the pygame module directly into your project directory.

The path to pygame on my mac after installing the binary is "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame".