# Pygame installation fails due to requirement of System Python 2.7, even though I have Python 2.7

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pygame

I'm trying to install pygame on my mac but I am getting the error

> pygame 1.1release can't be installed on this disk.
>
> pygame requires System Python 2.7 to install

[image: pygame requires System Python 2.7 to install]

I'm running python 2.7

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

I downloaded pygame from http://pygame.org/download.shtml and selected the file pygame-1.9.1release-python.org-32bit-py2.7-macosx10.3.dmg  I'm running osx 10.9.1

Why do I receive this error when I'm running Python 2.7 and how can I successfully install pygame on mac?

Comment: This issue might be happening if you have 64bit python, as pygame only supports 32bit python. Have you tried the fix suggested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300585/trouble-installing-pygame-on-mac-osx)?

Answer (score 4):

If you're running 10.9, you will need the [MacOS 10.7 build](http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip) or you can also [install using homebrew](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/82/homebrew-on-leopard-fails-to-install#comment-627494) or just [install from source](http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release.tar.gz).

I tested installing the 10.7 build on OS 10.9.2 and it worked fine.

Note that you will also probably need to install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing) to make it work on latests versions of OSX.