# Pygame is correctly installed but won't import in python 2.7 file

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pygame

***System:*** OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

***Language:*** Python 2.7 (must use 2.7 for class)

***IDE:*** LiClipse

***Background:*** For the longest time I could NOT get pygame to work *at all* in python. After much research I realized that pygame for mac is 32-bit while the general python 2.7 is 64-bit. So I uninstalled the 64-bit python and reinstalled 32-bit python 2.7.

***Problem now:*** When I enter IDLE, I am able to write

```
>> import pygame
>> print(pygame.ver)
```

and

```
1.9.1release
```

is successfully returned. No problem in IDLE

**HOWEVER**

When I enter LiClipse and simply run:

```
import pygame
```

The following is returned:

```
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

How is this possible if pygame can be imported in IDLE?

Comment: did you change your system python?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham hmm how would I do that?

Comment: I am not recommending, I am hoping you have not.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham oh. Hmm I have been messing around with a bunch of different things, perhaps I did - how would I know if I did or not?

Comment: what does `which -a python` output? A lot of your OS depends on the default version that comes with the OS, changing or removing can break your OS

Comment: This answer may also help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/21365230/2141635

Comment: Ok you have more than one version of python installed, run `/usr/local/bin/python` and `n /usrl/bin/python`, try importing from both and show which works.

Comment: Your output looks a bit strange also, you have repeats but I think you are safe as you most likely removed/reinstalled in /usr/local .

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I downloaded those two things and it worked!!!! Thank you for the help

Comment: no prob, just be careful with your system python

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your IDE is running the same python version and same PYTHONPATH environment variable (check `sys.version` and `sys.path` from both IDEs).

Comment: I went ahead and did that but now it says ImportError: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no appropriate 64-bit architecture (see "man python" for running in 32-bit mode)

Comment: Your IDE might still be using 64bit Python. See this answer to check which version they are running: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9964440/5274539