# install and use pygame on Mac Yosemite

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I installed Pygame on my mac using Anaconda.

```
pip install pygame
>>>Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

The thing is, I do not know to use it now. When I run a simple file from my code editor it says:

```
File "/Users/julien/untitled5.py", line 1, in <module>
import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

any advice ? I tried to run pygame using spyder from the Ananconda Navigator bun it does not seem to work either.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300585/trouble-installing-pygame-on-mac-osx

Comment: Thank you for your help Alex. I actually already did that and it only worked using IDLE. The thing is, I don't want to use IDLE. Trying to run pygame on any code editor different from IDLE does not work.

Comment: I'd love to help, but I'm on windows (switching to linux soon) Sorry :{ This may help, too https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/82/homebrew-on-leopard-fails-to-install

Comment: Thanks I appreciate ! I'll check that, meanwhile I'll get by with IDLE

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your IDE is looking in the wrong places for pygame. To see where it's looking for packages, run this script in the console for that IDE:

```
>>>import sys
>>>sys.path
```

This will show a list of paths where python looks for packages. `/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages` won't be there, which is why you can't import it. What IDE are you using? Most are able to change their settings so that they can import from different places, see if you can do that, and put `/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages` as part of the path.

Comment: As I do a lot of data science, I usually use Spyder, but maybe it isn't the right choice for pygame works ?